# Measure to count the categories based on values in power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a category and subcategory which has combination +ve, -ve and 0 values.I would like to create a measure to calculate the number of categories ( rows count)  which has a positive, negative and zero values. I have created the following for measures to calculate that but it returns the subcategories count rather than a categories count. Please refer the attached images. Anyone, please suggest me to find out.

```
+ve CategoriesCount = CALCULATE(COUNT('Sheet2 (2)'[Category]),'Sheet2 (2)'[Values] >0)

-ve CategoriesCount = CALCULATE(COUNT('Sheet2 (2)'[Category]),'Sheet2 (2)'[Values] <0)

zero CategoriesCount = CALCULATE(COUNT('Sheet2 (2)'[Category]),'Sheet2 (2)'[Values] =0)
```

[image]

Comment: Is that bottom right table the output you want? If not what is your desired result?

Comment: @AlexisOlson  yes Alexis. I want create a measure to count categories based on their values.

Comment: Your measure seems to work fine for me and generates the bottom table. What am I missing?

Comment: You may be after [`DISTINCTCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492142.aspx)